# How to solve the problem of saving image in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to save my image into database, it was moving into public folder but it doesnot saving into database. But while except image everything is working fine. And when save() method is called it gives me below error.[image: See the image for more information] .

Here what i have tried my code in controller

```
$student=new Student;
        $student->name = $request->input('name');
        $student->username = $request->input('username');
        $student->email = $request->input('email');
        $student->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $student->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $student->phone = $request->input('phone');
        if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $file=$request->File('image');
            $ext=$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename=$student->username . '.' . $ext;
            $file->move('images/',$filename);
            $student->image=$filename;
        }
        $student->save();
        $student->subjects()->attach($request->id);
        return back()->with('msg','Succesfully Added');
```

Comment: Why are you trying to move the file? can you try storing it: `$file->storeAs('images', $filename);`

Comment: yes error was gone but in the database save like a temp instead of name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `clientExtension()` instead of `getClientOriginalExtension()` and make sure your path is correct here I defined the path of public.

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $file = $request->image;
    $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/';
    $filename= $student->username . '.'.$file->clientExtension();
    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $student->image=$filename;

}
```

Comment: can you help me a little bit more regarding this

Comment: Yes, regarding what?

Answer (score 1):

**1) Make sure you have added enctype="multipart/form-data" in your form and a  with field name="image"**

**2) In your controller**

```
if( $request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $path = public_path(). '/images/';
    $filename = $student->username . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move($path, $filename);
    $student->image=$filename;
}
    $student->save();
```