# how to solve the problem of file does not exist in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am using a observer class to store image, everything works fine e.g. images are store in public folder, save in database but after the saving it will give me a error like below[image]

I tried this in my Student observer class

```
 protected $request;

    public function __construct(Register $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }
    public function created(Student $student)
    {
        //
    }
    public function creating(Student $student)
    {
        //dd($request->image);
        if ($this->request->hasFile('image')) {
            $file = $this->request->image;
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/';
            $filename= $student->username . '.'.$file->clientExtension();
            $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
            $student->image=$filename;

        }
    }
```

And in my controller

```
public function create(Register $request)
    {
        $student=new Student;
        $student->name = $request->input('name');
        $student->username = $request->input('username');
        $student->email = $request->input('email');
        $student->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
        $student->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $student->phone = $request->input('phone');
        $student->save();
        $student->subjects()->attach($request->id);
        return home('home');
    }
```

Comment: did you check if the image that is being move and saved are correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve the problem of saving image in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657680/how-to-solve-the-problem-of-saving-image-in-laravel)

Comment: yes that was my question but that time image was not saved at all and this time everything is work but got the error at the end

Comment: So, your first question was not rightfully answered right ? go check the answers on that question, you will find the solution to your issue

Comment: actually that time i used the whole code in my controller and one of the answer was right that time. But now i want to use it on observer class

Comment: is file exist in your project yet?

Comment: sorry i cant understand, which file? which i want to upload????

Comment: `/temp/phpO7...` this file

Comment: no i have a image which i try to upload but got the error saying that /tm/php...file doesnot exist